# Octave freqz command with fliplr --> Python syntax

Tags: python, octave

I'm trying to translate command

```
[h(:,m), w] = freqz(fliplr(b), fliplr(a),2048); % fliplr --> freqz works on powers of z^-1
```

from Octave to Python (w/ scipy (freqz) and numpy (fliplr)) but, it results error when written *as is*:

```
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in fliplr
  File "/home/xxxx/yyyy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 98, in fliplr
    raise ValueError("Input must be >= 2-d.")
ValueError: Input must be >= 2-d.
```

Which points to [fliplr](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.25.0/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L48-L99) function seem to work somehow differently compared to Octave's fliplr function.

Here are my *b* and *a* arrays:

```
b= [ 1.01063287e+00 -1.46490341e+01  9.94030209e+01 -4.19168764e+02
  1.22949513e+03 -2.66000588e+03  4.39112431e+03 -5.64225597e+03
  5.70320516e+03 -4.55022454e+03  2.85602975e+03 -1.39550096e+03
  5.20372994e+02 -1.43160328e+02  2.74037105e+01 -3.26098385e+00
  1.81735269e-01] 
a= [ 1.00000000e+00 -1.45159238e+01  9.86464912e+01 -4.16614074e+02
  1.22391361e+03 -2.65216678e+03  4.38533779e+03 -5.64421414e+03
  5.71487734e+03 -4.56742504e+03  2.87187255e+03 -1.40575405e+03
  5.25150201e+02 -1.44741759e+02  2.77584882e+01 -3.30950845e+00
  1.84797453e-01]
```

I've also tried by slicing w/ or w/o flipping:

```
[h[:, m], w] = freqz(np.flip(b[0:N]), np.flip(a[0:N]), 2048)
```

which of both passes compilation but, plots looks weird.

Any suggestions on translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays seem to be of rank 1 (i.e. 1-dimensional). The python error is telling you you're trying to flip along the second dimension, but there isn't one. Reshape your arrays to make them 2d. Presumably you want the values spread out along the columns, so the size of the rows will be 1 when you reshape. (so, given the way reshape works, you can pass -1 to the dimension you want to be calculated automatically, i.e. numpy.reshape( b, (1, -1) )

Comment: OK, it passes compilation that way (some differences in resulting h/w data but that might come from another place). I'll accept your answer.